# Rue and the evil eye

Tags: ayin-hara-evil-eye

Pele Yoetz by Rabbi Papo  states that the plant ruta/ruda, (pegim in Hebrew) Is mesugel neged ayin hara and witchcraft to whoever carries it. In practice I've heard of mekkubalim carrying this plant as well from another question here.

Is there a specific rue plant meant? Wikipedia lists like 7.

Comment: Welcome Neil. Well spotted in Pele Yoetz! What please did you mean by "mekkubalim caring this plant"?

Comment: Hi Neil. How about a specific page citation from Pele Yo'etz, link and quote in Hebrew. That would be helpful.

Comment: I'm unsure how to do so, link is Pele Yoetz 305:2  וכבר יש בספרים כמה סגלות להנצל מעין הרע, ובפרט עשב הרוד''ה שהוא מסגל מאד לנשאו עליו: